# Does @RequestBody accepts the not listed fields in the POJO class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I am using Postman to check my endpoints, So i have only 2 parameters in my POJO class, but when i added data using **JSON** through Postman API, i did add 1 extra parameter in JSON body (which is not there in my POJO). And it was a ok status and data is added while the **Extra** parameter got Ignored and i havent got any error which i should get Bad Request.

//controller

```
@PostMapping("/addpost")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addNewsPost(@RequestBody NewsPOJO newsPOJO) {
        System.out.println("In addPost block");
        System.out.println("The Received Data is:"+newsPOJO);
        return newsSearchService.saveData(newsPOJO);
    }
```

//service

```
public ResponseEntity<String> saveData(NewsPOJO newsPOJO) {
        System.out.println("In Service Class, save Data");
    try {
        newsPostRepo.save(newsPOJO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Not Added", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

//PostMan API
JSON BODY

```
{
        "title":"food",
        "content":"dkmdflkmbs",
        "Hello":5 //this field is not in my pojo
}
```

I want Postman to Send me an Bad Request if it happens.`your text`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by adding this below properties in your application.yml file

`spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true`

Which will ultimately throw an exception

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "extra_field" not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field
```